# Mechanical Turk 'rollback' on HIT Creation

Tags: python, mysql, mechanicalturk

Here is the code I currently have:

```
with transaction.commit_manually():
    try:
        m.update_accepted_url(episode_id)
        m.create_hit()
        m.do_insert()
        transaction.commit()
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
```

Now, what happens if the database operations fail -- and that rollback, but the `create_hit` goes through successfully? Is there a way to wrap the `create_hit` operation in something like a transaction, so if the db operations fail, that fails too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique token for your request, to avoid duplicates:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html

Comment: You should add more details to make this a complete answer. Link-only answers are generally discouraged.